# What kind of dirty-pinkish-flowered plant is this?

Tags: identification

I would like to know the species of this plant. It os 2ft tall, and consists of several spikes like pictured. It has nice tropical-feel foliage, with leaves organizes in star-like groups of 5 to 11 leaves, as visible in photos.

Also, if someone knows the kind of the bee, please tell me, it is important to me, because of polination.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: any insect that visits flowers is a pollinator, including bees, wasps, hover flies, even flies sometimes. I don't think this Lupin is a named variety, it looks like the ones that grow wild.

Comment: Right, but I was told that certain kind of bees is important for my orchard... Is this a bee or a wasp? What would be the latin name of common lupine? @Bamboo

Comment: It's a bee, not  sure  what type though. As for the Lupin, its generally spelt Lupine in the States, but Lupin in UK, latin name Lupinus. There are hundreds of named varieties, and they can be annual, perennial or shrubby in nature https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupinus

Answer (score 4):

This is a species of Lupine, in the legume family of plants (i.e. beans & peas, etc.) That's all I know. Someone else may come up with the exact species for you, ... and also the bee ID, but surely she is a pollinator, as you can see her saddlebags already full of pollen (on her hind legs).

Comment: I think it is Lupinus polyphyllus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupinus_polyphyllus)